# vuejs reactivity with variable initiated in mounted function

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I have a dynamic component building multiple select, the template :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-field
      v-for="(key,index) in allSelects"
      :key="index"
      :label="key"
    >
      <b-select
        :placeholder="key"
        v-model="values[key]"
      >
        <option
          v-for="(value,index) in optionsValues(key)"
          :key="index"
          :value="value"
        >
          {{ value }}
        </option>
      </b-select>
    </b-field>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the script is

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  data () {
    return {
      allSelects: ['select1', 'select2'],
      values: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    optionsValues: function () {
      return key => { return this.getData(key) }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function (key) {
      if (key === 'select1') {
        return ['valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'valD']
      } else {
        if (this.values.select1 === 'valA') {
          return ['A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'AAAA', 'AAAAA']
        } else if (this.values.select1 === 'valB') {
          return ['B', 'BB', 'BBB', 'BBBB', 'BBBBB']
        } else if (this.values.select1 === 'valC') {
          return ['C', 'CC', 'CCC', 'CCCC', 'CCCCC']
        } else {
          return ['D', 'DD', 'DDD', 'DDDD', 'DDDDD']
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // code
  }
}
</script>
```

In the mounted function, if I define the code as :

```
  mounted () {
    this.values = {
      select1: null,
      select2: null
    }
  }
```

Everything is working juste fine, the values of `select1` change the values of `select2`, but if I dynamically build it as following :

```
  mounted () {
    for (let val of this.allSelects) {
      this.values[val] = null
    }
  }
```

it's no longer working ! I would like it to be dynamic, the content of `allSelects` is dynamic in my real component. What would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Vue 2, aren't you? To add a reactive property to an object in Vue 2 you have to set it with `Vue.set()` (see [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)). So this should work:

```
  mounted () {
    for (let val of this.allSelects) {
      Vue.set(this.values, val, null)
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can initialize the object with the desired structure:

```
const selectIds = ['select1', 'select2']
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  data () {
    return {
      allSelects: selectIds.reduce( (s, i) => ({...s, [i]: null}), {}),
      values: selectIds,
    }
  },
```